# PHP+MySQL Запись в массив

Tags: массивы, php, mysql

Всем привет, необходимо выполнить запись в массив полученного значения из БД,если оно удовлетворяет условию. Вот код, но значения не выдает. Спасибо за помощь,прошу не кидаться камнями.

```
$ID=1;
$ans1 = Array();
for ($i=1; $i<21; $i++){
    if ($norm_getting[$i] ==1){
        $query = "SELECT * from sfer_name LEFT JOIN calc on sfer_name.id_sfer = calc.id_sfer where calc.ID = $ID and calc.id_sfer = $i and calc.norm_getting = $norm_getting[$i]"; // получаем значения из таблицы с полученными ответами
        $sql = mysql_query($query,$link)or die(mysql_error());
        $row =  mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $ans1[]=$row['sfer_name'];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйся. Это мой пример, подставь свой запрос и данные!

```
      $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(pd.birthday,'%d.%m.%Y') as birthday_edit
  FROM phone_directory pd
  WHERE pd.phone_category = '$category' AND pd.fio LIKE '%$search%'");
        $count=0;
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row[$count]){
            $count++;
        }
```

Результат будет в массиве $row[$count].

В твоем примере так же посмотри что бы запрос отрабатывался, потому что есть подозрения что есть ошибка в ситаксисе. А точнее  calc.ID = $ID должен писаться как calc.ID = '$ID'. Переменная должна быть в одинарных скобках.